# Returning a collection of related resources as URLs with an entity

Tags: sqlite, rest, servicestack

I'm writing a user service with servicestack and when a user resource is requested, I would like to return a collection of entities in the form of their respective URLs. The resources are friends of the requested user.

My current User entity

```
[RestService("/users")]
[RestService("/users/{Id}")]
[Alias("Users")]
public class User
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int      Id              { get; set; }
    public string   Name            { get; set; }
    public string   CellPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string   EmailAddress    { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate     { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially, in my SQLite database I would have a table called "Friendships" to express the relations. The table should work just fine like this

```
ID       PK INT NOT NULL
UserID1  FK INT NOT NULL
UserID2  FK INT NOT NULL
```

Do I need a "Friendship" entity to express this? What do I add/change to my User entity to have ServiceStack return it with a collection of Friendships?

I think a possibility would be a Friendship entity like so

```
[RestService("/users/{Id}/friends")]
[Alias("Friendships")]
public class Friendship
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id      { get; set; }
    public int UserId1 { get; set; }
    public int UserId2 { get; set; }
}
```

and when processing a request, return a collection of resource URLs for the user's friends. I'm not sure how to move forward with this and could use some hints/suggestions.

---

**Resulting Implementation**

I ended up keeping my Friendships table in the database but didn't implement a FriendshipService class and instead used something similar to what mythz suggested.

```
[RestService("/users/{Id}/friends")]
public class UserFriends
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I kept to mythz' UserFriends entity. My service class differs though that fit my need. The problem that his/her proposed solution didn't solve was that the user entity in question can be UserId1 or UserId2. So this is what with my service class to solve the problem.

```
public class UserFriendsService : RestServiceBase<UserFriends>
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    public override object OnGet(UserFriends request)
    {
        if (request.Id != default(int))
        {
            User user = DbFactory.Exec(dbCmd => dbCmd.GetById<User>(request.Id));
            var friendIds = DbFactory
                .Exec(dbCmd => dbCmd.Where<Friendship>("UserId1", request.Id).Select(fs => fs.UserId2))
                .Union(DbFactory.Exec(dbCmd => dbCmd.Where<Friendship>("UserId2", request.Id)).Select(fs => fs.UserId1));

            List<User> friends = DbFactory.Exec(dbCmd => dbCmd.GetByIds<User>(friendIds));
            return friends;
        }
        else
        {
            return DbFactory.Exec(dbCmd => dbCmd.Select<User>());
        }
    }
}
```

I could have selected User entities instead of the friend Ids by using the Ids selected and doing a `dbCmd.GetById<User>()` with them in the initial query but I think that would have made the code more convoluted and difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to hide the implementation details your services from your external APIs. In this case, I would return a list of User DTOs for each friend, e.g:

```
[RestService("/users/{Id}/friends")]
public class UserFriends {
    public Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserFriendsService : ServiceBase<UserFriends> {
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }
    public object Run(UserFriends request) {
        return DbFactory.Exec(dbCmd => dbCmd.Select<User>(
         @"SELECT u.* FROM Users u INNER JOIN Friendships f ON (u.Id = f.UserId2)
           WHERE f.UserId1 = {0}", request.Id));
    }
}
```

Note: it's not for everyone, but my preference is to wrap all ServiceStack responses in a Typed Response DTO. This provides a consistent convention/typed API for clients (i.e. they can predict the response for each service) and includes support for [typed Validation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation).

```
public class UserFriendsResponse {
    public List<User> Results { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That get's me pointed in the right direction. I should be able to use something like this. My query will differ a little though because seeing that these are friendship relationships, the user ID being queried may not be UserId1. For instance, a different user could request to add the user in question as a friend and they accept. Which would insert their Id into UserId2. I'll give your solution a try.